# Javascript: window.scrollTo / scroll are POST - how to make them GET (so they don't clear a form)?

Tags: javascript, post, get

I want to use Javascript window.scrollTo (or just scroll(0,0)) to click on a link and be taken to top of the page. But from what I understand, this Javascript:

```
onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)"
```

is a POST request?

In result, when I enter something into a form (textarea or input), the entered values disappear after I click on this window.scrollTo link: https://jsfiddle.net/8utxg4ux/

Is it possible to make this Javascript to be GET so that the form fields don't disappear after clicking on the TOP link?

Comment: GET and POST have nothing to do with clearing form values or scrolling behavior

Answer (score 1):

You want to add "return false;" to your onclick event in order to prevent the default behavior.

```
onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0);return false;"
```

Here's a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/oarzo5f2/

Or checkout the snipped here:

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<textarea></textarea>
<br><br>
<a href="" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0);return false;">TOP</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```